# Split CSV file based on characters in specific column

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a csv file, with a layout as follows:

| Easting | Northing | Elevation_OD | Chainage | FC | Profile | Reg_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 245932.499 | 200226.982 | 5.464 | 148.997 | CE | N/A | 8c12.11_021 |
| 245932.460 | 200225.448 | 5.214 | 150.530 | S | N/A | 8c12.11_021 |
| 245932.485 | 200224.993 | 5.111 | 153.222 | S | N/A | 8c12.1_001 |

The spreadsheet has ~55,000 rows and I need to be able to split the CSV based on specific research units - the '8c12.11' specifies a particular unit and the '_021' specifies a particular transect line and can be ignored. There are numerous units within this file and the character length of the units can vary e.g. '8c12.1' and I'm uncertain as to how to compensate for this alteration. Essentially the split needs to be able to identify the correct unit:

**8c12.11** - The characters prior to the transect line (e.g *_021*)

and then compile all of the associated rows that correspond to this unit, into a new table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using `extractBefore`

```
data.Unit = extractBefore( data.Reg_ID, '_' );
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in `data`, you can loop over all rows. In each row, call a `strsplit()` on the seventh column, splitting on the underscore. Then, either collect all unique units, or simply verify it against your desired unit.

Here's a quick mock-up of a code that does the latter:

```
idx_keep = zeros(size(data,1),1); % Initialise output indices
for ii = 1:size(data,1)
    B = strsplit(data(ii, 7), '_');  % Split the string
    if strcmp(B{1}, '8c12.11')
        idx_keep(ii) = 1;  % keep those indices that match
    end
end

my_unit = data(idx_keep,:);  % Now contains only the rows with unit == 8c12.11
```

In case you also want to check for specific transect lines, also check `B{2} == '021'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = 
readtable('Input/Wales_Interim_23/Pembrokeshire_23_Finished.csv');
unit_str = string(data.Reg_ID);
split = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x, '_'), unit_str, 'UniformOutput', 
false);
split_unit_cell = cell2table(split);
split_unit = splitvars(split_unit_cell)
unit = table2array(split_unit(:,1));

data.Unit = unit;
Ids = unique(data.Unit);
NID = numel(Ids);
```

This allows me to identify the amount of unique units within the CSV file, after splitting the unit name from the `Reg_Id` column.