# Iterate through a CSV and assign data into new tables, based on unique IDs

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I'm attempting to iterate through a CSV file and assign the data within each row into new tables, based on unique IDs. The unique IDs are found within the 'Unit' column - please find the formatting of the CSV file below:

| Easting | Northing | Elevation_OD | Chainage | FC | Profile | Reg_ID | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 245932.499 | 200226.982 | 5.464 | 148.997 | CE | N/A | 8c12.11_021 | 8c12.11 |
| 245932.460 | 200225.448 | 5.214 | 150.530 | S | N/A | 8c12.11_021 | 8c12.11 |
| 245932.485 | 200224.993 | 5.111 | 153.222 | S | N/A | 8c12.1_001 | 8c12.1 |

Essentially, I need to iterate through all of the rows and compile rows which belong to the same 'Unit' and then create subsequent 'Unit' tables.

Here's my code from [my answer on my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75593955/5211833) showing how I obtain the unique IDs:

```
data = 
readtable('Input/Wales_Interim_23/Pembrokeshire_23_Finished.csv');
unit_str = string(data.Reg_ID);
split = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x, '_'), unit_str, 'UniformOutput', 
false);
split_unit_cell = cell2table(split);
split_unit = splitvars(split_unit_cell)
unit = table2array(split_unit(:,1));

data.Unit = unit;
Ids = unique(data.Unit);
NID = numel(Ids);
```

Comment: Read [the docs on `unique()`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html). You can use the second (or third, I always forget which is which) output of `unique()` to index into the array. A loop over `1:max(ia)` then allows you to easily select all relevant rows and build a table from that. Something like `data(ia==3)` should give all rows with the 3rd unique Unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside: I added a much simpler way to generate the ID as a new answer to your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75601229/3978545).

You can generate a group number (one per unique ID) using `findgroups`

```
gidx = findgroups( data.Unit );
```

Then you can split the table by the group, and assign each group to a cell

```
N = max(gidx);         % gidx contains values [1,2,...,N] for N unique IDs
units = cell(N,1);     % pre-allocate an output cell
% Loop over the IDs and assign the subsets of data
for ii = 1:N 
    units{ii} = data( gidx==ii, : );
end
```

For what it's worth, you might want to think about your workflow. It's usually easier to continue manipulating data in a single table.